# Complex but efficient ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I must build an efficient query.

I have a Content Model declared as:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :major_labels
end
```

MajorLabel is declare as

```
class MajorLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contents

  def self.guides
    MajorLabel.where(name: 'Guida').first
  end
  def self.articles
    MajorLabel.where(name: 'Articolo').first
  end
end
```

I have also a class Article

```
class Article < Content
 mount_uploader :main_image, MainArticleUploader
end
```

Now, I need a query that return me all the Articles and all the Contents with MajorLabel 'Articolo'.

To return all the Article I can type

```
c = Content.where('type = ?', 'article')
```

I need to join this result with the Content with MajorLabel article...

How can I procede?

** edit **

To be more precise I need to join the results of two queries:

```
 MajorLabel.articles.contents
```

that return to me all the contents with MahorLabel articles and

```
 Article.all
```

that return me all the Articles.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are up to.But try this `MajorLabel.includes(:content,aricle).self.articles` untested though.

Comment: Is not easy. I have two type of articles: one type is the Article that inherit the Content class and the other type is the News with the MajorLabel 'article'. I need a query that return to me all of them.

Comment: question is not clear, where is the Article that inherit from Content class.

Comment: I edited my question... basically I have two type of articles, one with Class Article (that inherit from Content) and one with class Content and a MajorLabel "Article".